# Render children in vue.js Components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

How can I get the option into select in vue.js. React has something like `this.props.children`, which I used for such cases. How can I solve this in vue.js?

I tried also to access the children with $children, but is was always an empty array.

In this example, the selectbox hasn't the option's.
Have added the example also on jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kt8urx7d/

```js
var FormComp = Vue.extend({
    template: '#form-comp'
});
Vue.component('form-comp', FormComp);

var SelectField = Vue.extend({
    template: '#select-field'
});
Vue.component('select-field', SelectField);

var SelectFieldOption = Vue.extend({
    template: '#select-field-option'
});
Vue.component('select-field-option', SelectFieldOption);


new Vue({
  el: '#container',
  template: '<form-comp></form-comp>'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>

<script type="x/template" id="form-comp">
 <form>
   <h1>This is my Form</h1>
   <select-field name="my-select-field">
     <select-field-option value="my-value-1">My Text 1</select-field-option>
      <select-field-option value="my-value-2">My Text 2</select-field-option>
    </select-field>
  </form>
</script>

<script type="x/template" id="select-field">
 <select name="{{ name }}">
   <!-- include children: select-field-option -->
  </select>
</script>

<script type="x/template" id="select-field-option">
 <option value="{{ value }}">{{ content }}</option>
</script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Can you include the scripts, please?

Comment: I have added the scripts

Comment: Well, this is still incomplete, we are missing the templates for the components. My best guess is that the templates are wrong. For example, where is the label for the FormComp component (e.g. `<form-comp>`). Have you read the documentation? Please try to write your thoughts on a `jsfiddle` and we might be able to help you better.

Comment: I created following jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kt8urx7d/

How can i get the options into the selectbox?

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in the way you are rendering elements inside a component template. Take a look at this: https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots

On the other hand, Vue uses the browser's `HTML` rendering system, which means that elements that are "supposed" to be inside an HTML element get discarded. For example, `Vue` is expecting `option` inside `select`, and not `select-field-option`. To overcome this limitation you can do:

```
<option is="select-field-option" value="lalala"></option>
```

Reconsider the way you are using the templates inside the components. This could be useful for a headstart: https://jsfiddle.net/kt8urx7d/5/

Comment: I tried the slots feature. But I still don't know why is doesn't render my options: https://jsfiddle.net/n0osk4om/ :-(

Comment: It is a little bit frustrating. It works with the some-text component, but not with the select.. : https://jsfiddle.net/n0osk4om/2/

Comment: Don't worry, it'll happen eventually. Right now I'm not in front of my computer, but I'll be able to take a look in 2-3 hours.

Comment: You have the same problem that we mentioned before. From my original answer: "On the other hand, Vue uses the browser's HTML rendering system, which means that elements that are "supposed" to be inside an HTML element get discarded. For example, Vue is expecting option inside select, and not select-field-option."

This means you CAN'T use `<slot></slot>` inside a `select` element because the HTML parser in the browser discards the element before rendering it. Please take a look at my answer, I'd recommend to move the`select-field-option` BELOW the `select-field` component.

Comment: Hmm, okay. So their is no way to create a component which can do this: https://gist.github.com/tiefenb/b2622bb275cbd23ef040cd219c891686

Too bad..

Comment: Why not? You have to change the structure slightly and, again, probably move the logic of the options from being child of the select, instead of the app (which actually makes sense): https://jsfiddle.net/r62p3w5j/